# Add fitted model as PipelineStage in spark ML Pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I have a fitted word2vec model that I want to use in various projects.

That is I created a Word2Vec Estimator, fitted it to my dataset. This gives me a Word2VecModel, which I can save. How can I now add this model to a pipeline?

Preferentially, I would still like to be able to "fit" the pipeline, but exclude the Word2VecModel to be re-fitted. But this last part is optional.

Ideally I would want to do this in pyspark. But this is also optional.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it as is. For example if you have

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2VecModel 

w2vmodel = Word2VecModel.load(...)
```

you can

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

Pipeline(stages=[w2vmodel]).fit(df).transform(df)
```

Comment: That does not avoid having to re-fit the Word2Vec estimator.

Answer (score 0):

Not having to re-fit Word2Vec is quite simple. Fit whichever other estimators you need in Pipeline object `pipe1`, then create a PipelineModel object with Word2Vec as the first stage and `pipe2` as the second stage.

```py
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2VecModel, StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder

data = spark.read...

w2vmodel = Word2VecModel.load(...)

pipe1 = Pipeline(stages=[StringIndexer(...), OneHotEncoder(...)])

pipe1_model = pipe1.fit(data)

fitted_pipeline = PipelineModel(stages=[w2vmodel, pipe2_model])
```

Now you can use `fitted_pipeline` to `transform()` your data while keeping your Word2Vec intact.

If you need Word2Vec somewhere in the middle of your pipeline, you just need to break `pipe1` into multiple "stages" and compose your final object with `PipelineModel`